# sudoers.d file not working for a non-sudo user using three commands without password

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo, password

I want username steamy, a non-sudo user, to execute three commands (i.e., systemctl start|stop|restart factorio) without entering a password.

I am using sudoers.d file called factorio:

```
$ sudo ls -l /etc/sudoers.d/
total 8
-r--r----- 1 root root 174 Sep  4 16:49 factorio
-r--r----- 1 root root 958 Jan 17  2018 README
```

Contents of factorio file, that I created/edited with `$ sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/factorio`:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers.d/factorio      
steamy ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl start factorio, /usr/bin/systemctl stop factorio, /usr/bin/systemctl restart factorio
```

When username steamy is part of the sudo group, the three commands (i.e., systemctl start|stop|restart factorio) work correctly without requiring a passcode.

When username steamy is not in sudo group, the three commands require a passcode and fail when password is entered correctly.

Using Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS.

When steamy part of sudo group

```
$ sudo -l
Matching Defaults entries for steamy on steamnuc00:
    env_reset, timestamp_timeout=60, mail_badpass,
    secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin\:/snap/bin

User steamy may run the following commands on steamnuc00:
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
```

When steamy is not part of sudo group

```
$ sudo -l
[sudo] password for steamy: 
Sorry, user steamy may not run sudo on steamnuc00.
```

Comment: Add the output of `sudo -l` run as that user both when they are in the group and not in it, please

Comment: @muru I added the output to the response.

Comment: Is `@includedir /etc/sudoers.d` present in your `sudoers` config?

Comment: @muru Yes, it's there. $ sudo grep -i include /etc/sudoers
# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:
# includedir /etc/sudoers.d